# overlapping nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to solve the problem of overlapping nodes?
I want the below of n1.

```
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\tikzset{every node/.style={blue,rounded corners}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw,fill=yellow] (n1) {
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
        alignment of nodes

        with \verb|minipage|

        long text

        fourth line
    \end{minipage}
};
\node[draw,fill=orange!25] (n2) [below =1cm of n1.west,anchor=west] {below node};
\node[draw,fill=green!25] (n3) [right = of n1.north east,anchor=north west] {
    \begin{minipage}{5cm}
        right node

        with \verb|minipage|

        tirth line.
    \end{minipage}
};
\draw[<-,>=latex,red,very thick] (-.3,-1) to [out=0,in=180] (1,-1.5) node[right] {problem here.};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: i need below of n1.]

i need below of n1.

Comment: I myself decided. \node[draw,fill=orange!50] (n2) [below = of n1.south west,anchor=west] {below node};

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use `below = 1cm of n1.south west` instead of just `.west` if you want the node to be placed 1 cm below the bottom edge of the node. If you just write `.west`, the new node will be placed 1 cm below the middle of the other node.